# You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder_1' with dtype float

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

```
import tensorflow as tf

# H(x) = Wx + b

W = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1],name='weight'))
b = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1],name='bias'))

X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
Y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)

hypothesis = X * W + b

cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(hypothesis - Y))
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=0.01)
train = optimizer.minimize(cost)

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

Weights = []

for step in range(100):
    sess.run([cost,hypothesis,train], feed_dict={X:x_col[0],Y:y_col[0]})
    if step % 99 ==0:
        print(step, sess.run(cost), sess.run(W), sess.run(b))
```

This is the code I have. When I enter `x_col[0]` in Python Shell I get `array([  3.,   5.,  73.,  33.], dtype=float32)` and for `y_col[0]`, I get `array([  3.,   5.,  73.,  33.])`.

So I believe the code should work giving cost of 0 and W of 1 and 0 for b. But this error comes up. I don't know how I can fix this problem

For your information, for `sess.run([cost,hypothesis,train], feed_dict={X:x_col[0],Y:y_col[0]})`
I get `[960446.13, array([   76.92639923,   127.70278168,  1854.09997559,   838.57220459], dtype=float32), None]`.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Thanks for editing my question. Sorry I did not intend to come across that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `print` statement

```
print(step, sess.run(cost), sess.run(W), sess.run(b))
```

you are using `sess.run(cost)`, but cost is dependent upon `X` and `Y`, whose values you should provide as they are placeholders. So, you'll need to provide that in `feed_dict` as

```
print(step, sess.run(cost, feed_dict={X: some_x_value, Y: some_y_value}), sess.run(W), sess.run(b))
```

Comment: Sorry but I don't quite understand. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Hope it's clear now. Though you should follow @Maxim's advice, it is much more efficient that way

Answer (score 1):

@layog's answer is right. Just want to show you the code you should use:

```
for step in range(100):
  cost_val, W_val, b_val, _ = sess.run([cost, W, b, train], 
                                       feed_dict={X:x_col[0],Y:y_col[0]})
  if step % 99 ==0:
    print(step, cost_val, W_val, b_val)
```

It's more efficient to run the training op and compute tensor values in one shot (note that you don't have to specify `hypothesis`). If you want to explicitly compute any tensor, you'll have to pass the placeholders too:

```
sess.run(cost, feed_dict={X:x_col[0],Y:y_col[0]})
```

Answer (score 0):

In TensorFlow you define a computational graph that is executed with the `sess.run()` statement. As part of that graph the `cost` operation is defined by placeholder `X` and `Y`. To compute the `cost` you have to feed a value for `X` and `Y`.

In your `print` statement you call `sess.run(cost)` without feeding `X` and `Y`. That is the reason for the error.

But you already executed the graph. Just store the resulting values:

```
C, H, _ = sess.run([cost,hypothesis,train], feed_dict={X:x_col[0],Y:y_col[0]})
```

and print results for cost `C` and hypothesis `H`

Answer (score 0):

Check ***all*** the placeholders that you defined  earlier have been included/fed into the feed_dict. This is because during computation of your graph, the placeholders are created in memory, tensorflow will look ***if each one of them*** have been assigned real values inside the feed_dict, if not then it pulls such an error - at least for my case.

Answer (score 0):

I am using google colab and I faced the same problem.
I solved it by pressing the "runtime" option and in that I pressed "restart and run all" !

This restarted all of the code in google colab and the error no longer showed !